# Flutter - in_app_update Not Able to Show Update Dialog

Tags: android, flutter

Using This : https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update

Opened the app and tried to do InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate ()

print below log.

checkForUpdate InAppUpdateState{updateAvailability: 1, immediateUpdateAllowed: false, flexibleUpdateAllowed: false, availableVersionCode: 0, installStatus: 0, packageName: com.test.update, clientVersionStalenessDays: null, updatePriority: 0}

Also I have checked using internal App Sharing from google play console but not able to show Update Dialog.

Comment: Can you please share the implementations of this? I am also trying with this package but checkForUpdate is not working for me at all. It will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below flow to test In-App Update in internal app sharing:

1. Create two APK with different versions. Like (1.0.0+1, 1.0.1+2).
2. Upload both APK in internal app sharing. And install a lower version(1.0.0+1) app on your device.
3. Open a newer version link in the play store. Not update the app from the update button.
4. Now close the application and reopen the app which you are downloaded using the internal sharing app link. You will be able to get an update dialog.

For more info follow the below link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test